# Binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Present an algo to start with an initially empty BST and make 'n' random insertions.Use a uniform random number generator to obtain the values to be inserted.Measure the height of the resulting BST and divide this height by log2n.Do this for n=100,500,1000,2000,3000....,10000.Plot the ratio height/log2n as a function of n.The ratio should be approximately constant(around 2).Verify that this is so.
**My understanding**:
Now we all know that the height of a BST is log2n where 'n' is the number of elements in the tree.If it is a left skewed/right skewed tree,then the height is equal to 'n'. So,if we measure the height here,what height should we assume for the insertions are random.I mean,how could the ratio be always around 2.
I am banging my head against this one.

Comment: [THIS](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is a left skewed/right skewed tree,then the height is equal to 'n'. So,if we measure the height here,what height should we assume for the insertions are random

The height for such binary tree is `n`. You don't have to assume anything here. Moreover, height of perfectly balanced BST is log(n) (not in general)

---

Coming to your question, I assume you are asking to find height of randomly build binary tree. In that case you don't have to calculate height of any specific binary tree.

Even if the height of skewed tree is `n`, the probably of it being generated in uniform random distribution is very less. So, if you calculate the height of random BST, it will come out to be O(`log n`).

For accurate calculation, refer [Randomly build BST has logarithmic height](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/proof-that-a-randomly-built-binary-search-tree-has-logarithmic-height)

Comment: Yes I know that a randomly build BST has a logarithmic height......but what I'm asking is:how could the ratio be always close to 2......read my question carefully...do u have a solution?

Comment: Did you go through the link? They have shown expected height = 2*log (n)